# JSON to Python objects

Tags: python, json, api, class, object

I am deliberating about how to transfer the complex information from a JSON API response to (several) Python objects. I have included the (lengthy) model response below. Note that some values are not always included in the response, and some values are a list of dictionaries.

Is there an "easy" way to map the JSON response to Python objects? How would I ideally lay out the classes?

Model JSON response:

```
{
   "accounts" : {
      "accounting_reference_date" : {
         "day" : "integer",
         "month" : "integer"
      },
      "last_accounts" : {
         "made_up_to" : "date",
         "period_end_on" : "date",
         "period_start_on" : "date",
         "type" : "string"
      },
      "next_accounts" : {
         "due_on" : "date",
         "overdue" : "boolean",
         "period_end_on" : "date",
         "period_start_on" : "date"
      },
      "next_due" : "date",
      "next_made_up_to" : "date",
      "overdue" : "boolean"
   },
   "annual_return" : {
      "last_made_up_to" : "date",
      "next_due" : "date",
      "next_made_up_to" : "date",
      "overdue" : "boolean"
   },
   "branch_company_details" : {
      "business_activity" : "string",
      "parent_company_name" : "string",
      "parent_company_number" : "string"
   },
   "can_file" : "boolean",
   "company_name" : "string",
   "company_number" : "string",
   "company_status" : "string",
   "company_status_detail" : "string",
   "confirmation_statement" : {
      "last_made_up_to" : "date",
      "next_due" : "date",
      "next_made_up_to" : "date",
      "overdue" : "boolean"
   },
   "date_of_cessation" : "date",
   "date_of_creation" : "date",
   "etag" : "string",
   "external_registration_number" : "string",
   "foreign_company_details" : {
      "accounting_requirement" : {
         "foreign_account_type" : "string",
         "terms_of_account_publication" : "string"
      },
      "accounts" : {
         "account_period_from" : {
            "day" : "integer",
            "month" : "integer"
         },
         "account_period_to" : {
            "day" : "integer",
            "month" : "integer"
         },
         "must_file_within" : {
            "months" : "integer"
         }
      },
      "business_activity" : "string",
      "company_type" : "string",
      "governed_by" : "string",
      "is_a_credit_finance_institution" : "boolean",
      "originating_registry" : {
         "country" : "string",
         "name" : "string"
      },
      "registration_number" : "string"
   },
   "has_been_liquidated" : "boolean",
   "has_charges" : "boolean",
   "has_insolvency_history" : "boolean",
   "is_community_interest_company" : "boolean",
   "jurisdiction" : "string",
   "last_full_members_list_date" : "date",
   "links" : {
      "charges" : "string",
      "filing_history" : "string",
      "insolvency" : "string",
      "officers" : "string",
      "persons_with_significant_control" : "string",
      "persons_with_significant_control_statements" : "string",
      "registers" : "string",
      "self" : "string"
   },
   "partial_data_available" : "string",
   "previous_company_names" : [
      {
         "ceased_on" : "date",
         "effective_from" : "date",
         "name" : "string"
      }
   ],
   "registered_office_address" : {
      "address_line_1" : "string",
      "address_line_2" : "string",
      "care_of" : "string",
      "country" : "string",
      "locality" : "string",
      "po_box" : "string",
      "postal_code" : "string",
      "premises" : "string",
      "region" : "string"
   },
   "registered_office_is_in_dispute" : "boolean",
   "sic_codes" : [
      "string"
   ],
   "subtype" : "string",
   "type" : "string",
   "undeliverable_registered_office_address" : "boolean"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Python provides a `json` module, from which you can "load" the data from JSON to Python. In this example, if `response` is a variable representing your big blob of JSON, you can do:

```
import json
py_object_collection = json.loads(response)
```

If this does not work for you, it will require that you specify the expected output result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, and you want to take a json object and abstract it to a class, you can do this with a class and `setattr()`.

This goes through each key in the json, if the value of the key is not a `dict`, it sets the attribute (with the name of the key) to the value.

If the value of the key ***is*** a `dict` it creates a new instance of `JsonToObject`, and repeats the above process with the new object, and sets the attribute (with the name of the original key) to the new instance of `JsonToObject`.

```
import json

class JsonToObject:

    def __init__(self, json_object):
        self.json_object = json_object
        self.keys = json_object.keys()
        self.setup(json_object)

    def setup(self, d):
        for key, item in d.items():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                new_object = JsonToObject(item)
                setattr(self, key, new_object)
            else:
                setattr(self, key, item)

# I am reading from a file with the contents you specified.
# If you are reading the json from a variable instead of a file,
# take away the `with open...` line and use 
# `d = json.loads(json_content)` instead of `d = json.load(f)`
with open("test.json", "rb") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

json_obj = JsonToObject(d)

print(json_obj.accounts.accounting_reference_date.day)
print(json_obj.annual_return.next_due)
```

#### Otherwise, if you only want to load json into memory and access it like a python dictionary:

```
import json

with open("test.json", "rb") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

print(d["accounts"]["accounting_reference_date"]["day"])
print(d["annual_return"]["next_due"])
```

### Both examples give the same output:

```
integer
date
```